# Api call fills one array but not the other?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So im calling my firebase backend which fills the items array. When I console.log the items array everything is there but when I setData to items and console.log the data array it is empty. So why is the setData not working. The data array only appears correct after a rerender but not initially.

```
const [data, setData] = useState<DocumentData[]>([]);
const [loader, setLoader] = useState(true)

async function getData() {
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("bagels")
ref.onSnapshot((query) => {
  const items: SetStateAction<DocumentData[]> = []
  query.forEach((doc) => {
    items.push(doc.data())
  })
  if(items){
    setData(items)
    setLoader(false)
    console.log(items)
    console.log(data)
  }
})
}

useEffect(() => {
getData()
}, [])

return (
<div className="App">
  <h1>BAGELS!</h1>
  {loader === false && (data.map((doc) => {
    <div key={doc.id}>
      <h1>Name: {doc.name}</h1>
      <p>Price: {doc.price}</p>
    </div>
  }))}
</div>
);
}
```

Comment: setData is an asynchronous useState call. it will only set the value on its next render. not in the next line, console it just before your return or in a useEffect hook

Comment: ok but shouldnt using setData cause a rerender as it is changing the state? @sojin

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items: SetStateAction<DocumentData[]> = []

async function getData() {
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection("bagels")
ref.onSnapshot((query) => {
  query.forEach((doc) => {
    items.push(doc.data())
  })
})
}

useEffect(() => {
getData().then(()=>{
    setData(items)
    setLoader(false)
})
}, [])
```

Hope it'll help.